# Flutter Align element from Column in line with Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I need to build the following design:

[image]

Until now I created a Row that contains the 3 dots Icon, A column with the Circle avatar, a line and the plus Icon and the Input.

I can't figure own how to align the center of the row (Input) with the center of the cercle avatar...

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.drag_indicator),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: this.index > 0,
            child: VerticalLine(),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            elevation: 8.0,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(this._getLabel()),
              radius: 25.0,
            ),
          ),
          VerticalLine(),
          Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded, size: 15.0),
        ],
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: DropdownSearch<String>(
          mode: Mode.MENU,
          showSelectedItems: true,
          items: ["Brazil", "Italia (Disabled)", "Tunisia", 'Canada'],
          label: "End",
          hint: "country in menu mode",
          popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
          onChanged: print,
          selectedItem: "Brazil",
          maxHeight: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

This is how it looks:

Any idea how to align the center of the Circle Avatar with the center of the Input horizontally?

[image]

Comment: hmm when you try to add the DropdownSearch in an container and set alignment: Alighnemn.center of the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that it is in fact centered, but compared to the complete Column that has the avatar and the lines.

I would suggest this structure instead (pseudocode)

```
Column:
    topline
    Row:
        dots
        avatar
        dropdown
    bottomline
    icon
```

That way those are aligned nicely. The problem you will have now though is that those lines won't be aligned nicely. You probably will need to give the column `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` and wrap the lines with a padding to add space to the left side of them according to your likeing

Comment: Yeah I realized the problem and fixed it in a similar fashion as you described in the answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @exilonX yeah your solution is also great.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I had created a transparent line on top of the first CircleAvatar to have everything simetrical and I also moved the add_icon as a row below the row of the input:

```
Container(
          color: this.index == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.pink,
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.drag_indicator),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          VerticalLine(
                            transparent: index == 0,
                          ),
                          Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            elevation: 8.0,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                              child: Text(this._getLabel()),
                              radius: 25.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          VerticalLine(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: DropdownSearch<String>(
                        mode: Mode.MENU,
                        showSelectedItems: true,
                        items: ["Brazil", "Italia (Disabled)", "Tunisia", 'Canada'],
                        label: "End",
                        hint: "country in menu mode",
                        popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
                        onChanged: print,
                        selectedItem: "Brazil",
                        maxHeight: 50.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 42.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded, size: 15.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

herepretty easy. you need to put the circle and input items in a 'div' block with styles display:flex align-items: center ,
set display: block to the image, and margin: 0 to any '' tag

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center"> 
<img src='/images/avatar10.png' width="41" height="41" alt="" class="img-radius me-1 " style="display: block" /> 
<h4 class="color-main" style="margin: 0">21341241</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be useful for a flutter explanation, the layout building is pretty different